# QGIS Composer - Exported Map layer diagonal fill becomes solid (dense)

Tags: qgis, export, print-composer, fill

When I export my compiled map from QGIS to JPEG or PDF the fill pattern becomes solid rather than diagonal lines.  I am exporting at 600dpi when to JPEG.  But it is clear that the diagonal lines are still in the image but just highly condensed creating the appearance of a solid polygon feature. Which suggests to me that I am missing some export scale setting somewhere?

Also the point class features appears less clear in the exported image below.

Below is a screenshot of the map in composer:

[image: This is a screen capture of the image in composer note the visible diagonal lines and clearly defined point features]

When I Export the map to either JPEG or PDF the following is the result - note the change from a diagonal fill to a solid and reduced point feature clarity:

[image: Note the lack of Diagonal lines and less clear point features]

This is not a major problem but the idea is exporting the map that I spent a few hours compiling rather than a slightly different variant of the map.

I hope that it is a simple setting somewhere that I am unaware of that is condensing the fill pattern when exporting -- I am no GIS expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it worked if you set the type of filling from Simple to Line Pattern Fill and the distance within the Pattern to Milimeter:

[image]

Comment: Aleho that worked perfectly.  I just had to add another simple fill element to allow for a border around my polygon.